# nested group by in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, bigdata

In Spark, I'm grouping by a Food Inspection Data set on the name of the restaurant. In the following example, it is "ZED 451". Thus, the key is "ZED 451" and the value is a list of all the inspections related to this restaurant.

```
(u'ZED 451', [(u'1975848', u'ZED 451', u'ZED 451', u'729-743 N CLARK ST ', u'60654', u" u'41.89574704893414'", u" u'-87.6310791667675'"), (u'1609466', u'ZED 451', u'ZED 451', u'729-743 N CLARK ST ', u'60654', u" u'41.89574704893414'", u" u'-87.6310791667675'"), (u'1139101', u'ZED 451', u'ZED 451', u'729-743 N CLARK ST ', u'60654', u" u'41.89574704893414'", u" u'-87.6310791667675'"), (u'114380', u'ZED 451', u'ZED 451', u'729-743 N CLARK ST ', u'60654', u" u'41.89574704893414'", u" u'-87.6310791667675'")])
```

Now, I'm trying to do a secondary group by on this grouped by dataset. The secondary group by I want to do is on lat and long to identify the branches of "ZED 451" that are the same. I've tried out all the possible methods to do a second group by but without any success. Any help on how to proceed with that without using Spark SQL or Spark DataFrames will be appreciated.

PS: I would want my output to look like this:

```
(u'ZED 451', [(u'41.89574704893414', u'-87.6310791667675'", [(u'1975848', u'ZED 451', u'ZED 451', u'729-743 N CLARK ST ', u'60654'), (u'1609466', u'ZED 451', u'ZED 451', u'729-743 N CLARK ST ', u'60654'), (u'1139101', u'ZED 451', u'ZED 451', u'729-743 N CLARK ST ', u'60654'), (u'114380', u'ZED 451', u'ZED 451', u'729-743 N CLARK ST ', u'60654')])]
```

In this case, all the instances of restaurants point to the same branch so there's one lat and long key and it's value is a list of all those instances. But in other entries, multiple branches with multiple lat's and long's exist.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: After the first groupBy, instead of a second groupBy, how about using mapValues? array[restaurant] -> array[ (long, lat, array[restaurant]) ]. Just a thought

Answer (score 1):

groupBy (name, long, lat).
Then groupBy name